# Display both code and image with R Markdown HTML when making PDF from within the code

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr

I'm creating an `R Markdown` HTML document where I want to display the following code together with the resulting plot image:

```
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4) 
plot(cars) 
dev.off()
```

The problem is with the `pdf()` and `dev.off()` functions. When I run the above code with `echo=F`, it will repress all the code from being displayed and just generate PDF externally without displaying any image.

````
```{r, echo=F}
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```
````

When I run this code with `eval=F`, it will display the code, but obviosly without producing the image.

````
```{r, eval=F}
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```
````

The only solution I found so far is to have two separate chunks of code - one for displaying the code using `eval=F`, and another for displaying the image where I repress the code with `echo=F` and just use code for plotting the image, with PDF production:

````
```{r, eval=F}
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```

```{r, echo=F}
plot(cars)
```
````

Its not very sustainable approach so I would prefer to do it with just a single code chunk. I tried Yihui Xie's various [ways for chunks output control](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/) but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are repeatedly using `pdf` and `dev.off` in your rmarkdown but never want to execute them, one solution would be to redefine them to do nothing.

````
```{r,echo=FALSE}
pdf <- function(...) Sys.sleep(.1)
dev.off <- function(...) Sys.sleep(.1)

```

```{r fig.show="hold"}
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```
````

Of course, this should be used carefully, since it might mess up other bits of code in your document. You could still access the normal function with `grDevices::pdf()` and `grDevices::dev.off()`

Comment: It gives me the following error: `Error in dev.off(dv) : unused argument (dv)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> dev.off
Execution halted`

Comment: @GeekOnAcid : adding `...` to the function definitions should take care of it. See my updated answer

Comment: Almost there but the code chunk gets broken when displayed in HTML document and `dev.off()` is moved after the plot figure - any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @GeekOnAcid add chunk option `fig.show="hold"`. See http://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant enough but you could add a 2nd `plot(cars)` to the chunk and suppress its output with `echo=-4`.

````
```{r, echo=-4, results="hide"}
pdf("plot.pdf", width=6, height=4)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: Thank you, interesting approach. However, its still problematic if I have a lot of plot options to include (like text, various tweaking, etc.). So I'm trying to find a solution which avoids repetition of the image code.